# meteor reactiveVar not updating results in html

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am writing a meteor application and using teh reactivity feature to implement auto update of results on the dom when its available or on update.
here is my code snippet:

```
    Template.message.helpers
      profession: ->
        return Template.instance().profession.get()

    Template.message.onCreated ->

     @profession = new ReactiveVar ''

     msg = Template.currentData()

     @userId = msg.u?._id

    Tracker.autorun =>
        Meteor.call 'getLimitedUserData', {id:Template.instance().userId},  (error, result) =>
            if error
                return handleError(error)
            if result
                @profession.set result.customFields.Profession
```

dom:

```
   {{#if profession}}
        <span class="profession"><i>{{profession}}</i></span>
    {{/if}}
```

what could I have done wrong? the profession doesn't get updated.. But if I log it in console it prints teh right values.

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: is that coffee script? since i don't know it, i would look at the generated JS to ensure that, inside the callback for the Meteor method, the scope of the reactive var for profession is the same scope as that of the template.

Comment: yes its a coffee script and yes its in the same scope but for some reason the DOM doesn't update the value

Comment: I would debug by 1) putting console.log in helper to see how many times it's called and what value you have and 2) inthe template hardcoding text ("here!") inside if to see if the conditional is working.

Comment: your use of autorun doesn't make any sense. What do you expect this to do? Are you perhaps assuming that a change of data on the server will trigger that method call to be executed automatically? If so, then you are on the wrong track. Method calls are not "reactive data sources", i.e., they do not trigger a recomputation. Either call the method call yourself (and the rest will be reactive), or use a subscription (which is what I think you want).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Tracker.autorun()` will never run because it doesn't depend on any reactive data source except for the `userId`. If you're already logged-in when you open this template then `userId` is not changing.

You can do the `Meteor.call()` in the template's `onCreated` handler and then when it returns (asynchronously) your helper will update automatically.

```
Template.message.helpers
  profession: ->
    return Template.instance().profession.get()

Template.message.onCreated ->
  @profession = new ReactiveVar ''
    Meteor.call 'getLimitedUserData', {id:Template.instance().userId},  (error, result) =>
      if error
        return handleError(error)
      else
        @profession.set result.customFields.Profession
```

*However:* Why are you using a `Meteor.call()` to get information about the user? This would normally be handled through a pub-sub on the user collection. This would give you the benefit of reactive updates as well as simplifying your template pattern - you shouldn't need a reactive variable to display information about the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know the implementation of your `getLimitedUserData` on the server, I'd assume two situations:

1. "Limited user data" is a set of limited data from your MongoDB on the backend, in which you'd want to use `Meteor.publish` and `Meteor.subscribe` instead.

   ```
   // on the server
   Meteor.publish('limitedUserData', function() {
     return Meteor.users.find({ /* limits */ });
   })
   ```

   and the Blaze code:

   ```
   Template.message.onCreated(function() {
     this.autorun(() => {
       this.subscribe('limitedUserData')
     })
   })

   Template.message.helpers({
     profession() {
       return Meteor.users.find({ /* same limit */}).profession
     }
   })
   ```
2. "Limited user data" is an API call to an external service, which would be a little bit complicated. You'll probably need to use some combination of DPP and setInterval, etc.